# Change Node express Timeout try connection

Tags: node.js, express, settimeout, async.js, connection-timeout

i'm trying to change the timeout of a post express method using node-expose-sspi for authentication.
The problem is, none of what i tried worked so far.
My goal is to set the connection timeout 5s instead of the standard 120s.

When i enter the right credentials the code take approximately between 0.3s and 1.5s, and when the credentials are wrong the code takes between 7s to 120s

The "actual" code is:

```
const app = express();

app.post('myRoute', async (req, res) => {
   try {
    const domain = sso.getDefaultDomain();
    const credentials: UserCredential = {
        domain,
        user: req.body.login,
        password: req.body.password,
    };
    
    const ssoObject = await sso.connect(credentials);
    if (ssoObject) {
        req.session.sso = ssoObject;
        return res.json({
            sso: req.session.sso,
        });
    }
} catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).json({
        error: 'bad login/password.',
    });
}
});
```

What i've tried so far was:

Change globally setTimeout:

```
var server = app.listen();
server.setTimeout(5000);
```

Change res inside the method:

```
 res.setTimeout(5000, () => {
  console.log('Request has timed out.');
  res.send(408);
});
```

And Promise race:

```
let promisseConnect = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    const domain = sso.getDefaultDomain();
    
    const credentials: UserCredential = {
      domain,
      user: req.body.login,
      password: req.body.password,
    };
    
    const ssoObject = await sso.connect(credentials);
    
    if(ssoObject){
      resolve(ssoObject);
    }else{
      reject(401);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    reject(401);
  }
})

let promisseTimer = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let wait = setTimeout(() => {
    clearTimeout(wait);
    resolve(408)
  }, 1000)
})

Promise.race([
  promisseConnect,
  promisseTimer,
])
.then((res) => console.log(res))
.catch((res) => console.log(res))
```

All of then didn't showed any error messages as far i remember, just the usual message after tried connection for 120s.

Comment: What is the value of `ssoObject` in your "actual" code after this line `const ssoObject = await sso.connect(credentials);`?

Comment: When correct, it return the data i was looking (in json), but if the credencials are wrong it goes to catch block.